# Conversion between int and char not working as expected

Tags: scala

To convert a `char` to its `Int` equivalent I use:

```
scala> 'a'.asDigit
res2: Int = 10
```

I expect to convert `10` to char `a` by using `toChar` method:

```
scala> 10.toChar
res3: Char =
```

But `a` is not being returned.

How can you convert and un-convert a digit to char?

Comment: `97.toChar` is `'a'`, by the way.

Comment: ASCII `10` is a linefeed, so it looks like everything is working as it should?

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes, everything is working as it should, I made incorrect use of API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `asDigit` and `toInt`. If you want the `Int` equivalent of 'a' in terms of the Ascii character set then use `toInt`.

```
scala> 'a'.toInt
res12: Int = 97

scala> 97.toChar
res13: Char = a
```

To see why `10.toChar` does not print anything check out the [character tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`Character.forDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html):

```
'a'.asDigit  // res1: Int = 10

Character.forDigit(10, 16)  // res1: Int = 10
```

Note that the `RADIX` value for `asDigit` is 16 (hexadecimal), and using another one is likely to cause encoding problems. Scala uses [`RichChar`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/runtime/RichChar.scala#L1) to wrap a character and supply the `asDigit` function. This uses the underlying conversion provided by Java `Character` class, the relevant documentation for which is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-int-int-).

To understand a little of what is going on here, note that `10` is the **decimal** representation of `a`, which is the hexadecimal representation for `10`. That is, in **hexadecimal** the tenth number on the number line is `a`. This is a different representation than when you're converting to unicode characters, say, but it gets confusing because:

```
'a'.asDigit  // res1: Int = 10
'b'.asDigit  // res2: Int = 11
'f'.asDigit  // res3: Int = 15
'g'.asDigit  // res4: Int = 16
'z'.asDigit  // res5: Int = 35
```

So, what is happening is that your character is converted to a hexadecimal number which is then being represented as an integer. But converting from an integer to a character directly doesn't work.